# Piecewise linear (PL) structures on $\mathbf R^4$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, 4-manifolds, topological-manifolds

One can read in Wikipedia that the 4-dimensional affine space $\mathbf R^4$ has uncountably many piecewise linear structures (in contrast with other dimensions, where it has exactly one). A reference is given to Milnor's paper, [*Differential Topology Forty-six Years Later*](http://www.ams.org/notices/201106/rtx110600804p.pdf) where this fact is indeed printed on the bottom of the first column of page 2.

However, I could not follow the arguments that lead to this conclusion, nor find them in the litterature (eg, Freedman-Quinn's book).

Results of the 60s imply (Theorem 2 of Milnor's quoted paper) that any PL structure on $\mathbf R^4$ gives rise to a well-defined, compatible, smooth structure. Then Freedman classified topological closed 4-manifolds, and Donaldson proved that many of them cannot be smoothed. But how does this help constructing exotic PL structures on $\mathbf R^4$?

Comment: Would Taube's result that there are uncountably many exotic smooth structures on $\mathbb{R}^4$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4) be the missing piece of your puzzle?

Comment: There are three facts: (1) existence of uncountably many non-diffeomorphic exotic $\mathbf R^4$'s. (2) any smooth manifold has a PL structure. (3) Any PL manifold of dimension $<7$ has a smooth structure that is unique up to diffeomorphism. For the latter two facts see 1.5 and 1.8 in the survey http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0885 where explicit references are given.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thanks! I had missed (2). If you write your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three facts:

1. existence of uncountably many non-diffeomorphic exotic $\mathbf R^4$'s.
2. any smooth manifold has a PL structure.
3. Any PL manifold of dimension $<7$ has a smooth structure which is unique up to diffeomorphism.

For the latter two facts see 1.5 and 1.8 in [this survey](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0885) where explicit references are given.

Comment: For dimension $<7$, is it even correct to say that the category of smooth manifolds and the category of PL manifolds are equivalent?

Comment: @Student: sorry don't know much about categories. Can you rephrase the question without using the word "category"?

Comment: Basically I want to find a correspondence on the maps too. More precisely (related [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320205/is-there-a-constructive-proof-that-in-four-dimensions-the-pl-and-the-smooth-cat)), let $X, Y$ be smooth closed $4$-manifolds, and $X', Y'$ be the corresponding PL closed $4$-manifolds. Can we find an assignment $\Phi$ that sends any smooth map $f: X \to Y$ to a PL map $g: X' \to Y'$ and $\Psi$ that goes in another direction, such that $\Psi \Phi (f)$ is smoothly homotopic to $f$, and that $\Phi \Psi (g)$ is PL homotopic to $g$?

Comment: @Student: To me it seems the functors should be PL or smooth homeomorphisms (not merely maps). I would look at "Obstructions to the Smoothing of Piecewise-Differentiable Homeomorphisms" by Munkres who deals with this kind of issues, and "Obstruction theories for smoothing manifolds and maps" by Hirsch.